# Want to add alert if searchTerm length ==0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
            //appendTo:"#abc",
            // position: { my : "right top", at: "right bottom" },
            source: "home/search",
            minLength: 1,

            autoFocus: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("form").submit();
                }
                else { alert("abc")}
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried several things but somehow i m not able to crack this simple thing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
if($.trim($("#searchTerm").val()).length === 0) {
    alert("empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the .value is a string then..

```
if (ui.item.value.length == 0)
```